# Why don't my twins sleep for a longer stretch of time?

Tags: infant, sleep

My twins are 4 1/2 months old. They are exclusively breastfed. We start our bedtime routine at 8: we take a bath, breastfeed, then rock to sleep. By 10 they will be asleep. However, each 2-3 hrs they will wake up to breastfeed. They never slept for more than that.

Is this normal? Aren't they supposed to sleep for a stretch of 5-6 hours yet?

Comment: Doesn't sound unlike my two daughters.

Comment: Sounds totally normal to me. Unfortunately. That's how things were in our family.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate of... well pretty much every question under the sleep tag. http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sleep